# Convert a Blank Site to a Team Site

Tags: publishing-site

I am new to Sharepoint.  I created a site from a blank site but I am not sure how to convert what I created to a Team Site so that my coworkers have access to it.  Please help

Comment: Delete the site and create a new one as Team site.

Comment: You cannot convert a site into another because the Schema of the site is Read Only. You have to delete that site and create another one as Daniel states

Answer (score 1):

A template is essentially a starting point used to create a site. For example the team site includes document library, an announcements list, a calendar, a contacts list, and a links list.

This could all be created manually using a blank site if you wished. As Daniel stated if you don't have any content yet your best bet might be to delete the site and recreate as a team site. However if the issue is permissions related which it appears it may be, you can grant permissions to a blank site the same way you would a team site.

Here are some related articles for managing permissions.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/manage-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010-team-sites.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287708(v=Office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Blank sites and team sites are just varying templates. Anything in a team site you can recreate in a blank site by creating the proper lists and what not.

What you are referring to is access and permissions. Users need to be granted access by going to Site Actions and selecting Site Permissions. Find the desired group and click Add Users. Enter the desired users into the box and hit OK and the users will now be able to access your site.